# How to query nested mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have a collection called 'Profiles', and it has a structure like this:

```
{
_id : XXXXX,
classrooms:{
   owner:[],
   students: [XYSk0,CCD7U],
},
...
}
```

I want to get profiles that has `classrooms.students` equals to `CCD7U`.

I have tried using `$elemMatch` on the collection publish function, but unsuccessful:

```
Meteor.publish('StudentsInClassrooms', function(CCD7U){
   return Profiles.find({ classrooms : { $elemMatch :{ students : CCD7U }} });
});
```

I even tried dot notation, but still unsuccessful:

```
Meteor.publish('StudentsInClassrooms', function(CCD7U){
   return Profiles.find({ 'classrooms.students' : CCD7U });
});
```

How to properly query that kind of nested collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the "$in" operator for such query.

```
Profiles.find({ 'classrooms.students' : { $in :['CCD7U'] } } )
```

Ref: [MongoDB documentation; $in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

Answer (score 0):

When you normally query something you would do it

```
Profiles.find( { 'classrooms': 'classroomName' } );
```

But because your are trying to find something from nested you need to do it like this

```
Profiles.find( { 'classrooms': { 'students' : CCD7U } } );
```